# Exception Java main ArrayList error with java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class DecimalToBinaryExample2{

    public static void toBinary(int decimal){
    int binary[] = new int[40];
    int index = 0;
    while(decimal > 0){
    binary[index++] = decimal%2;
    decimal = decimal/2;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(100);
        
        ArrayList arry = new ArrayList();
        arry.add(n);
        
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            arry.add(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            System.out.println(arry);
            
            int arrayStore = ((CharSequence) arry).length();
            if (arrayStore == 100) {arry.subList(50, 100);}
                
        } 
        
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.CharSequence.
```

Comment: `(CharSequence) arry` what do you expect this to do and why are you doing it in the first place? Why don't you just check its size with `arry.size()`?

Comment: And unrelated, but your next problem will be that `arry.subList(50, 100);` doesn't modify the list in place but returns a sublist.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast that in that way. Instead of `((CharSequence) arry).length()` you can just use `arry.size()`.